# GET command in httr not returning anything after minutes

Tags: r, httr

I'm trying to access NBA's stats api which doesn't particularly have any documentation, but after a few hacks I've figured out how to construct the URL to retrieve the appropriate data

For example - http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreadvancedv2/?GameID=0021600001&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=0&EndPeriod=0&StartRange=0&EndRange=0&RangeType=0

This works perfectly fine on the browser, but when I try to use R's httr package to retrieve the same page, the command just runs forever without returning anything. Am I doing the command wrongly?

```
nba <- httr::GET("http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreadvancedv2/?GameID=0021600001&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=0&EndPeriod=0&StartRange=0&EndRange=0&RangeType=0")
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Not alot of sympathy (or aid) for you since you're violating T&C #1 http://www.nba.com/news/termsofuse/

Comment: Oops thanks, I wasn't aware - I'm not going to bother continuing.